# How to store Visio drawing in a SharePoint column

Tags: c#, sharepoint, vsto

Is there a way to store a Visio drawing in a SharePoint (2010) site column?

I'm working on a solution to automate a document (MS Word) assembly, using SharePoint List data. One such data type is Visio. Is there a way to store Visio in a List, without storing it inside a Word document, which would then need to be retrieved and parsed in order to extract the Visio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can't store it in a column per-se, you do have a few options:

The most simple is to create a document library and let each drawing be a document, and add any needed columns to the list definition or content type for your library.

If that won't work, typically because you would need to have a parent (like a word document as you mentioned) - many lists have the Attachments field which you could use to attach an arbitrary number of drawings (or other files) to.

You could also come up with a parent-child relationship using multiple libraries that may prove the most flexible and robust of all the solutions. You can define a column on the child list that is a lookup back to the parent list (probably the ID column would be a good choice if it is all automated).